# Compare NSArray in a for loop with given input with nspredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nspredicate, string-comparison

i really don't know how to ask this since it was really painful to come up with a question title but i hope you will be able to help me

I got a plist.

i read it  into an nsarray

```
NSArray *arrayOfPlist = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

this pList is in this format.

```
<array>
    <dict>
                <key>category</key>
        <string>desert</string>
        <key>numberOfPerson</key>
        <string>3</string>
        <key>recipeImage</key>
        <string>asdasd.jpg</string>
        <key>time</key>
        <string>15</string>
        <key>recipeName</key>
        <string>asd asdad</string>
        <key>recipeDetail</key>
        <string>asdasd</string>
        <key>recipeIngredients</key>
```

User enters inputs into a textField.

where i store it as searchText

and i use NSPredicate to see if RecipeIngredients contains it.

At this point i m having troubles

When i try to use this array

```
        NSArray*        haves = [recipeIngredientsOfOneRecipeString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@","]];
```

it gives me this error  `[<__NSCFString 0x109291950> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key recipeIngredients.'`

And the other thing is i can not imagine a proper way to check all recipeIngredients with given input.

I tried adding a bool predicate each time it returns true i incremented and when its count became same as haves.count i added it but this doesn't work either.

i am killing myself for a way to solve these problems and i m out of of ideas.

need a new perspective.

Comment: you have array of dictionaries not array in plist

Comment: @Pandey_Laxman where did i assume that i don't have array of dictionaries can you point it out?

Answer (score 1):

You can enumerate whole plist file to match the user input using the below code

```
NSArray* arrOfPlist = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSString* strMatch;//user Input
    for (NSDictionary* dict in arrOfPlist)
    {
        for (id key in dict)
        {
            if ([[dict objectForKey:key]isEqualToString:strMatch])
            {
                //user search matches do whatever code you want here

                break;
            }
        }
    }
```